# preg_match validating date of birth

Tags: regex, preg-match, date

I've got this so far:

```
$post_dob = '19/08/1982';                      
$pattern = '/^\[0-9]{2}\/\[0-9]{2}\/\[0-9]{4}\$/';


if(!preg_match($pattern, $post_dob)){                                
    $post_dob = explode('/', $_POST[$field]);
    $post_dob = $post_dob[2] . '-' . $post_dob[1] . '-' . $post_dob[0];  
    return $post_dob;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

It doesn't seem to go wrong if i put **19/08/19823123**
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `/` is a special character, either you escape it using `\/` or use a different pattern sequence like `@^[0-9]{2}/...@`.  And don't escape the last `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$pattern = '@^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$@';
```

But in reality, its much complicated than that.  You'll have to consider leap years and months having 30 days versus 31 days, etc.

Comment: What does the @ stand for

^ = start of string
$ = end of string

@ = ?

Comment: @JamesT well if you have too many `/` in your pattern, then instead of writing the regex within `//` in which case you'll have to escape each `/` within your expression, you can use any other character.  See <http://us.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php>.

Comment: Thanks for the leap year advice. I was hoping jquery date picker would solve that... It was mainly to prevent the hackers from typing in crap. Cheers !!!

Comment: I got you with the @. Nice one. I'll test my new skills on domain checking. Thanks a bunch. Answered.

Comment: so If I were to do something like this for email validation: **/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/** This would be fine because I don't use / anywhere else? P.S why wouldn't this one work?

Comment: @JamesT it should, I didn't bother to check against any e-mail but yes since it does not contain any `/' it should work.

Comment: I was being a noob. yes it does work. Great thanks once again. Have an awesome evening.